# python selenium - Why cant I click this?

Tags: python, selenium, click

https://gyazo.com/9887635aa04d723758ba17b3413f72e1 - the html

the one named class="radio inline bundle-cta" is the one i want.

```
<label class="radio inline bundle-cta">
            <input data-bind="checked: activeBundle" id="BundleType" name="BundleType" type="radio" value="Default">
            Nej tak, jeg vælger en basisannonce uden tilvalg
                <span class="uneditable-input price">Kr. <span data-price="0">0</span>,-</span>

            <span class="bundle-cta-button">Vælg basisannonce</span>
        </label>
```

error msg, when trying to click it:

```
Element is not clickable at point (604, 698). Other element would receive the click: <p style="line-height: 20px; margin: 0px 40px 0px 15px; padding: 0px;">...</p>
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

code I used to try to click it:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.class, "bundle-cta-button"))

# vælg gratis pakke
browser.find_element_by_class_name('bundle-cta-button').click()
sleep(0.75)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div/div/form/div/button').click()
```

Comment: Can you paste the link you are trying to click on? `Element not clickable` exception is raised when your browser can't see the element in the visible scope of your screen. Maybe you will have to scroll your selenium `webdriver` a little to bring the element into the right position.

Comment: Its not a link I am trying to click, its rather a "check button" U know u click on it and it either goes True or False.

https://gyazo.com/cfd209222bb4cf2244d0e165805a3214 Here is what I am trying to click

The text on it says: "Nej tak, jeg vælger en basicannonce uden tilvalg."

Comment: Have you tried using [explicit waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html?highlight=expected_conditions#explicit-waits) to see if the element exists before you click on it?

Comment: What do you mean by scrolling my webdriver? That I have to manually scrol l down the website? Or what do you advice me?

Comment: I havent tried explicit waits, I have just made a "sleep(5)" And hoped that was enough. I will inset explicit waits on all places instead now. Thanks
I completly forgot about them

Comment: Nope that wasnt the cause of the error. the explicit waits didnt help...
Any other idea?

Comment: Can you update your question with the explicit wait code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128097/discussion-between-sebastian-nielsen-and-kiran-koduru).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change spaces into dots, and find by CSS_selector like below:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("radio.inline.bundle-cta").click()
```

Comment: Look at the second lowest line of the html. The class I want is:
bundle-cta-button which there is no blank spaces in to replace by a dot.

My question might not be totally accurate since I have tried a lot of diffrent things to try to make it work, and then updated the question.

But do u have any other idea of what the cause of the error might be?

Comment: The problem is that when you try to click on coordinates of this span, there is another span nearby (the one with x-btn-icon-el class), which has the same size and coordinates. That's why both Firefox and Chrome raises such error.

A proper solution to this would be to adapt your tests to click on anchors, not their internal spans. For example, in this case you would click on "//a[normalize-space()='Yes']" element.

Closing this because it works as expected.

Comment: The problem is that when you try to click on coordinates of this span, there is another span nearby (the one with x-btn-icon-el class), which has the same size and coordinates. That's why both Firefox and Chrome raises such error. A proper solution to this would be to adapt your tests to click on anchors, not their internal spans.

Comment: Forget about my 2 previous messages. I think you first need to  find the previous item, and then click on the main structure.

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1867#issuecomment-203306818

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"radio.inline.bundle-cta"}

it wasnt able to locate that either :(

Here is a gif of what I am trying to click, its the button at the lower part of the page, that turns yellow: https://gyazo.com/364840b17ad94b85afc4ab6b67a40afd

Comment: Uh I just saw the github link. How can I adapt my code to click on the anchors? Thats the only part I didnt get.

Comment: But the solution wasnt only that I had to click the anchors it was only, that everytime I enter the page. A little "do u accept the cookies" sign pop up in the button of the page. Potentially blocking for the button to be clicked. 

Now I just gotta figure out how to automaticly close the "accept cookies" pop up >.<

Comment: Actually the little "accept cookies" pop up in the button could be avoided if I just scrolled to the button of the page.

Do u know how to code the script a way so it jumps down to the buttom of the page?